# XMLLite parser hangs

Tags: parsing, visual-c++, mfc, xmllite

I'm parsing an XML using XMLLite. I notice that when its a relatively large file, the reader's pointers fails to locate the next element(tag) of the file. When i reduced the contents of the file, it could successfully parse.

The reader continually shows node type "XmlNodeType_None" and fails to complete parsing, getting stuck in an infinite while loop.

Is it to do something with its file size? Or anything in initializing the IStream? My file has around 9000 bytes of data only.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Do not use the SUCCEEDED macro to check if you should continue processing the value returned by IXmlReader::Read.  Instead, check that the return value of IXmlReader::Read is equal to S_OK for the condition of your loop.